# Load AngularJs service in factory

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a shopping cart and my shopping cart have a set of rules, which are being loaded from json and is only needed to validate the cart.

To my understanding (could be wrong) its good practice to load external contact using services and use factory to modify objects. and if that's true I think I need to load the service in my factory.

If my assumptions are correct, is it possible to load the service in factory ? if so can I just load service in factory as I load in controller?

Many Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject services into other services (factories) in the same way like you do it in controllers